# Get only first element from database

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I want to show bought "products names" in prestashop orders page.
For prestashop 1.6 i already have a code that works, but using the same code on prestashop 1.7 give me duplicate orders ...

```
public function getProductsName($id_order, $tr)
{
    $products=Db::getInstance()->executeS(
        'SELECT product_name FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail
        WHERE id_order='.(int)$id_order);
    $str='';
    foreach($products as $val) {
        $str.=substr($val['product_name'],0,35).'| ';
        }
    $str=trim($str,'|');
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you provide that within your asnwer.

Comment: Forgot to add screens: 
http://shrani.si/?3Q/7T/3WRCZeru/presta16.jpg

http://shrani.si/?44/QQ/YiOJLlA/presta17.jpg

I see no error if i use the code i wrote for 1.6 but instead i get duplicate order like in screenshoot.

Comment: But the `product_name` is different. Maybe here is an additional language field?

Comment: There are more Producrt names on same order yes. I would like to get only the first Product name like in presta1.6.jpg screen or better get all of them but in "one line".
Problem is i get duplicate entries instead of one entry with "first" Product name or better one entry with all product names.

Comment: This is the prestashop 1.7 database entry ...

http://shrani.si/f/3N/cB/2lKr6AoV/859d6e10-88eb-42ca-8b8d-.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a sulution. Apart from the script i posted above i added to AdminOrdersController.php this piece of sql:

a.id_order AS product_name,

and added to product_name array:

'callback' => 'getProductsName',

and retouched the script to remove the last |:

see updated script in first post.

all changes are in AdminOrdersController.php

Thanks for all.

Final result: http://shrani.si/f/28/pH/2jxmMrf7/qq-photo20190704132806.jpg

Comment: There's no need to post your own answer, especially since it doesn't add anything new. If you think any of the existing answers have the solution to your question, please accept that by giving it the green check mark.

Comment: Ok sorry, i was thinking that it would help someone with same problem. I does add some new things ... but ok, sorry again like i said.